# using Third Party Slider and couldn't navigate to another view

Tags: ios, swift

i am currently using KYDrawerController for a slider menu and I couldn't navigate to another page. Whenever I press a button (even without codes in it), it crashes. Another is i tried to set another view as initial view, it doesnt shows that. I am suspecting it's something to do with my appDelegate file. I need some troubleshooting help around if possible. I changed my AppDelegate file to

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

var drawerController = KYDrawerController.init(drawerDirection: .left, drawerWidth: 300)

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let mainVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainMenu")
    let menuVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "drawer")

    self.drawerController.mainViewController = mainVC
    self.drawerController.drawerViewController = menuVC

    self.window?.rootViewController = self.drawerController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```

anything here might have been the problem?

Comment: my simulator keeps showing me the mainVC regardless of where i set my initial view, and any button I clicked in my mainVC even without codes in it, it crashes

Comment: maybe this reference can help you! if not let me know here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36950237/how-to-navigate-to-different-view-controllers-based-on-slide-out-menu

Comment: Don't worry about that Use this library. It is very easy and simple .     https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu

Answer (score 1):

Your are missing to embed your view controller in `navigationController`. Please update your code for `mainVC` as follows and try again.

```
let mainVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainMenu")
let mainViewNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainVC)

self.drawerController.mainViewController = mainViewNavigationController
```

I hope this will fix your issue. Let me know if still facing any issue.